# class derived from class template using base:base in body

Tags: c++

This is likely a basic question, but I haven't seen this done before and I haven't found a reference that talks about it:

What is going on in the following code:

```
using HandlerType = std::function<bool()>;

class SpecificAction : public Action<HandlerType>
{
public:
    using Action::Action;
};
```

Specifically, what is the reason for the 'using Action::Action'?  Action is a class template with a bunch of methods defined for it, but this is the entire declaration for SpecificAction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are defining a class SpecificAction deriving from Action, everything in Action is added to SpecificAction, except the constructors. This syntax is a way to tell the compiler that you want to use the constructor from Action as a constructor for SpecificAction.
The reason constructor are not added by default to the derived class is that the derived class is likely to add some more data members which will not be initialized by the base constructor. Using this syntax you're telling the compiler that it's ok, you know what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks shoosh, makes perfect sense now.